# How to get client id and secret for a console application so as to get access token for Smartsheet in C#

Tags: smartsheet-api

To get access token through program, the smart sheet documentation tells to register the third party application using the Developer tools option which requires "APP URL" and "APP Redirect URL".

My application being a console application how can i specify "APP URL" and "APP Redirect URL".

**What I have tried:**

I tried access token generated from smart sheet by manually clicking "Generate New Access Token" by going into Account(settings)> Personal Settings> API Access.
But this Access token is said to expire in 7 days.[Access token validity as said in this link](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#refresh-an-access-token)

Hence i want an access token to be generated through program so that i can Refresh the Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access tokens generated through the UI do not expire. The doc you reference applies only to access tokens obtained through the OAuth flow.

Comment: "Access tokens generated through the UI do not expire" that answers my question.